# check 1st row of a column with all rows of anothter in python (panda)

Tags: python

I have two text files. First file contains those cols,

> ['Start time', 'End Time', 'Activity']

second file contains

> ['Start time', 'End Time', 'Location', 'Type', 'Place'].

I want to check for example 
Start_time1[0] with all rows of Start_time2.
The code is

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Fri Jun 09 15:04:08 2017

@author: Owner
"""



import pandas as pd
#import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time
import datetime
import numpy as np



df = pd.read_csv("OrdonezA_ADLs.txt", header = None, delimiter=' *\t+ *', engine='python')
df.columns=['Start time', 'End Time', 'Activity']
df2 = pd.read_csv("OrdonezA_Sensors.txt", header = None, delimiter=' *\t+ *', engine='python')
df2.columns=['Start time', 'End Time', 'Location', 'Type', 'Place']
#print df2.head()
print df['Start time'][0]
print df2['Location'][0]

df['Start time'] = df.apply(lambda row: time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(row['Start time'], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").timetuple()), axis=1)
df['End Time'] = df.apply(lambda row: time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(row['End Time'], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").timetuple()), axis=1)

#print df


df2['Start time'] = df2.apply(lambda row: time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(row['Start time'], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").timetuple()), axis=1)
df2['End Time'] = df2.apply(lambda row: time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(row['End Time'], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").timetuple()), axis=1)
#print df2



p = np.zeros(shape=(len(df),12))

print p

for x in xrange(len(df)):
    for y in xrange(len(df2)):
        if (df['Start time'][x] == df2['Start time'][y]  and df['End Time'][x] <= df2['End Time'][y]):
            if df2['Location'][x] == 'Shower':
                print "Shower on"
#                p[x,0]=1 here i want to add 1 in first col of p,in x row of p
            elif df2['Location'][x]=='Basin':
                print "Basin on"
#                p[x,1]=1
            elif df2['Location'][x]=='Door Kitchen':
                print "Door Kitchen on"
#                p[x,2]=1
            elif df2['Location'][x]=='Door Bathroom':
                print "Door Bathroom on"
#                p[x,3]=1
            elif df2['Location'][x]=='Maindoor':
                print "Maindoor on"
#                p[x,4]=1
            elif df2['Location'][x]=='Fridge':
                print "Fridge on"
#                p[x,5]=1
            elif df2['Location'][x]=='Cupboard':
                print "Cupboard on"
#                p[x,6]=1
            elif df2['Location'][x]=='Toilet':
                print "Toilet on"
#                p[x,7]=1
            elif df2['Location'][x]=='Seat':
                print "Seat on"
#                p[x,8]=1
            elif df2['Location'][x]=='Bed':
                print "Bed on"
#                p[x,9]=1
            elif df2['Location'][x]=='Microwave':
                print "Microwave on"
#                p[x,10]=1
            elif df2['Location'][x]=='Door Bedroom':
                print "Door Bedroom on"
#                p[x,11]=1           

        else:
            print ("not")
```

Can anyone help me please? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you transform the date string to datetime and then to timestamp.

Use `merge` with `inner`option to extract only the matching cases for both columns that you are looking for.
The code will be something like:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Start_time': [1,2,3], 'End_time': [1,2,3], 'Activity': [4, 5, 9]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Start_time': [1,2,3], 'End_time': [3,2,1], 'Location': ['x','y','z'], 'Type': [7,8,9], 'Place': ['a','b','c']})
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='inner', left_on=['Start_time','End_time'], right_on=['Start_time','End_time'], left_index=False, right_index=False, sort=False)

for i in df['Location']:
    if(i=='y'):
        print 'Ok'
    else:
        print 'Error'
```

Where only one row has 'Start_time' and 'End_time' in common.

Comment: after the first if condition??

Comment: I updated the code with the conditionals. I used a `for` loop in case the merge result gives multiple rows output